# Осуществление заказа без сайта

Tags: javascript, python, html, http

Возникла необходимость создания заказа в мвидео без использования сайта, например через телеграм бота на питоне
Хочу осуществить это путем отправки post запроса.
Как посмотреть куда уходит запрос и что входит в его тело?
Пробовал найти это в девтулс хрома, но в среди запросов отсутствует необходимый с форм дата атрибутом. На просторах интернета советуют fiddler, пытался посмотреть через него, но безупешно - не видна сессия от браузера
Путем изучения сайта, на странице подтверждения заказа нашел следующую форму:

```
<input data-submit-btn="true" data-sel="new_checkout-button-order_submit" name="/com/mvideo/commerce/singlepage/order/CommitSingleOrderFormHandler.commitSuborder" value="Сделать заказ" onclick="window.dataLayer.push(window.mvideo.helpers.gtmMutationFunctions['checkoutOrder']({
                &quot;event&quot;: &quot;OWOX&quot;,
                &quot;eventAction&quot;: &quot;click&quot;,
                &quot;eventCategory&quot;: &quot;Conversions&quot;,
                &quot;eventLabel&quot;: &quot;orderButton&quot;,
                &quot;bonusRoublesHolder&quot;: &quot;.c-line-img_icone-br + .wrapper-text__rouble:first&quot;,
                &quot;discountHolder&quot;: &quot;.o-available-stock&quot;,
                &quot;deliveryRadio&quot;: &quot;newShippingMethod&quot;,
                &quot;eventPosition&quot;: &quot;1&quot;,
                &quot;eventParameter&quot;: &quot;site&quot;,
                &quot;orderPartsTotal&quot;: &quot;1&quot;,
                &quot;paymentRadio&quot;: &quot;choosenPaymentMethod&quot;,
                &quot;pickupSeamless&quot;: &quot;false&quot;,
                &quot;ecommerce&quot;: {
                    &quot;checkout&quot;: {
                        &quot;actionField&quot;: {&quot;step&quot;: &quot;5&quot;, &quot;option&quot;: &quot;confirm order&quot;},
                        &quot;products&quot;: [{
                    &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Смартфон Xiaomi Redmi Note 10S 6+64GB Gray&quot;,
                    &quot;id&quot;: &quot;30057494&quot;,
                    &quot;price&quot;: &quot;21999&quot;,
                    &quot;brand&quot;: &quot;Xiaomi&quot;,
                    &quot;category&quot;: &quot;Смартфоны&quot;,
                    &quot;dimension101&quot;: &quot;cat3_cis_0000000865&quot;,
                    &quot;dimension102&quot;: &quot;1083&quot;,
                    &quot;dimension104&quot;: &quot;promo&quot;,
                    &quot;dimension112&quot;: &quot;cat1_cis_0000000012&quot;,
                    &quot;dimension113&quot;: &quot;Смартфоны и связь&quot;,
                    &quot;dimension114&quot;: &quot;0&quot;,
                    &quot;dimension123&quot;: &quot;0&quot;,
                    &quot;metric14&quot;: &quot;27999&quot;,
                    &quot;variant&quot;: &quot;site&quot;,
                    &quot;quantity&quot;: &quot;1&quot;
                }]  }   }   
    }));" class="c-btn c-btn_text o-checkout__submit-button" type="submit">
```

Comment: добаления товара в корзину https://www.mvideo.ru/bff/cart/add

Comment: Это именно добавление в корзину, а интересует, передача самого заказа, с методом оплаты, забора и т.д. В форме по клику вызывается функция, вот как бы ее посмотреть, чтобы понять полный перечень пар ключ: значение даты и юрл принимающий эти значения